# How to find a SQL query results with different column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I used the query

```
select *
from account
where transaction_ID = 18256
```

and I was able to get the result that I wanted. It gave me the column `account_number = 5.48129651984531E18` and `transaction_ID = 18526`.

I tried searching the data by using the query:

```
select * 
from account
where account_number = '5.48129651984531E18'
```

and did not get any results.

I tried `where account_number = 5481296519845310000` and it still did not work. I also used single quotes for `account_number = '5481296519845310000'` and it still didn't give me any results but I should be getting the same results when I used the first query `where transaction_ID = 18256`.

I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: This is a good example of why you should make account numbers strings and not numbers. An account number doesn't have calculations done on it, so should not be a numeric type. Just because it happens to have all digits 0-9 in it doesn't mean it should be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from account 
where account_number = CAST(CAST('5.48129651984531E18' AS FLOAT) AS bigint)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get such output just because of wrong formatting settings.
For example in sqlplus:

```
SQL> show numformat
numformat ""
SQL> select 12345678901234567890 + 1 x from dual;

         X
----------
1.2346E+19

SQL> set numformat tm9
SQL> select 12345678901234567890 + 1 x from dual;

                    X
--------------------
12345678901234567891

SQL> select to_char(12345678901234567890 + 1, 'tm9') x from dual;

X
--------------------
12345678901234567891
```

So just use `to_char(account_number, 'tm9')` to output it correctly without round up

Comment: If the account number were a string and not a numeric value, then these sorts of shenanigans would not be necessary.